# Proof the following - language

Tags: relations, formal-languages

Theorem $4$. A language $A$ is regular iff there exists a regular expression $\alpha$ such that $A = L(\alpha)$.

Check whether the following equations are correct.

1. $\left((a\cup b)^*\right)^*=(a\cup b)^*$;
2. $(a\cup b)^*(a\cup b)^*=(a\cup b)^*$.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want a proof for the theorem, an answer for the second paragraph, or what?

Comment: The theorem isn’t actually relevant to the exercises. Both equations are correct, but how you’re supposed to verify them depends enormously on how rigorous your course is. Informal verifications are pretty trivial; formal ones will depend on exactly how you defined your regular expressions.

Comment: the question should be prove 1 and 2 that they are equal. We have to proof if for example for 1.  if ((a∪b)∗)∗ subset of  (a∪b)∗ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Your question has nothing to do with regular languages. Look carefully at the definition of $L^*$ (where $L$ is any language, regular or not) and try to prove the following properties

1. $(L^*)^* = L^*$
2. $L^*L^* = L^*$